# Keydown event does not fire a function

Tags: javascript, events

I've made a simple code which should change visibility of box while certain key is pressed,but something is wrong because whichever button will be pressed it always says it's wrong.

This should work only while "f" key is pressed,right now it doesn't work at all...

```
const brick = document.querySelector('.brick');

window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e)
{ 
    e.preventDefault();

    if(e.keycode == 70)
    {
        let x = event.keyCode;
        console.log(x);
        brick.style.visibility = "visible";    
    } else {
        let x = e.keyCode;
        console.log(x);
        console.log("You've pressed wrong button")
        brick.style.visibility ="hidden";
    }

});
```

[Code is Here](https://jsfiddle.net/zucodz55/)

I know i can use jquery but i would like to do this in pure JS

Greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight syntax error:

```
if(e.keycode == 70)
```

should be:

```
if(e.keyCode == 70)
```

Notice the capital C.

Comment: Yep, I was going to post this too. Also i was wondering how he defined `let x = e.keyCode;` and not noticed the camelcase difference? Cause in the end the console log was working :)

Comment: Indeed @DincaAdrian, i think OP may have been tired at the time!

Comment: Thank You very much guys ! everything is working like a charm :D

Answer (score 0):

This may helpful . After run the code press key "F" in the keyboard to see the red div

```js
const brick = document.querySelector('.brick');
window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e)
{ 
        e.preventDefault();
        let x = e.keyCode;           
         if(x == 70)
         {
            
            //console.log(x);
            brick.style.visibility = "visible";                     
                    
        }            
         else
        {           
            //console.log(x);
            //console.log("You've pressed wrong button")
             brick.style.visibility ="hidden";
         }
            
  });
```

```css
.brick
    {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        visibility: hidden;
        background-color: red;
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="brick" >
        
 </div>
```